# getElementById Visual Studio VB - DIV tags are ignored

Tags: javascript, css, vb.net

I have HTML code as follows:

```
<div id="test" style="display: none;"> Hello World </div>
```

I am using the WebBrowser component in Visual Studio on my form. The page loads as expected but when calling the follow line:

```
MessageBox.Show(wbr_main.Document.GetElementById("test").InnerText)
```

originally Visual Studio threw an error saying there was no element with ID of "test".
After lots of frustration and researching I changed the DIV to a SPAN and it actually worked. That was honestly the only change I made. I thought, "Ok weird." So to test I changed it back to a DIV and it worked. As of writing this the code is working using the DIV tag. My question is, why would changing the tag and then changing it back correct my problem? I have a feeling it's a caching issue but I'm unsure.

Comment: Do you get different results using `InnerHTML` instead of `InnerText`?

Comment: @JohnPavek Unfortunately not. When the issue had presented itself using InnerHTML and InnerText yielded the same result. Furthermore, I've tried to reproduce the issue tonight and haven't been able to.